# Give an user a warning when he tries to include a signature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, signatures, warning

[Data Explorer - People that use their name in their post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1850/people-that-use-their-name-in-their-post).
<sub>(Well, matches `rob` inside a word, but that's just a matter of correcting the regular expression; it's the idea that counts...)</sub>

Can't we warn people when they try to include their name in their post near the end?

Some thoughts:

1. Split the post in 2 or 4 and only check the last part.
2. Along his name, check for common words `With kind regards`-like sentences and words.
3. Based on statistics, see whether we need a warning or we could automatize this.

Comment: Some salutation-like things are already [automatically detected and removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989).